# How to optimize mysql queries containing DATE_ADD()?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Here is the query which needs to be optimized:

```
Scans: 527676 records...
Returns: 496 records...

SELECT * FROM customers c
WHERE DATE_ADD(c.`custdate` ,INTERVAL -5 HOUR) BETWEEN '2011-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2011-09-14 23:59:59'
AND c.`custtype`='L'
```

---

This is the same without using DATE_ADD:

```
Scans: 801 records...
Returns: 481 records...

SELECT * FROM customers c
WHERE c.`custdate` BETWEEN '2011-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2011-09-14 23:59:59'
```

Question is how should I optimize this query using DATE_ADD() function? Without using DATE_ADD it picks up my indexes and query is fine.

Awaiting help on this.

Thanks,

Raheel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're just adding a constant time interval to `c.custdate`, what should work is instead to subtract that time interval from the `BETWEEN` values, to obtain a query that's logically equivalent but permits MySQL to use the index. In general, if the query requires evaluation of a function of the index values, a range scan can't be used.

That is: instead of the `WHERE` clause being

```
DATE_ADD(c.`custdate` ,INTERVAL -5 HOUR) BETWEEN '2011-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2011-09-14 23:59:59'
```

make it

```
c.`custdate` BETWEEN '2011-09-14 05:00:00' AND '2011-09-15 04:59:59'
```

Comment: Totally agreed - MySQL can't use indexes when you're performing a function on the field in question, so always try to perform the function on the filter criteria instead of the field. MySQL can then use the available indexes

Comment: ... in addition, it is totally possible to perform the "DATE_ADD" function on each of the values in the the "BETWEEN" clause, as MySQL will optimize those away where possible. E.g.  "c.`custdate` BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2011-09-14 00:00:00' INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AND DATE_ADD('2011-09-14 23:59:59' INTERVAL 5 HOUR)"

Comment: Yes it works.. As you suggest to add 5 hours to both the dates in between clause to get similar results as of GMT-5, do you know a handy function to add 5 hours to the datetime so that i may refactor all the queries using date_add.

Comment: As you suggested, now i use DATE_ADD function in the criteria and not on the field, however while i was using interval -5 hour in the field, now i use interval +5 hour in the criteria...

SELECT * FROM customers c
WHERE 
c.`custdate` BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2011-09-14 00:00:00' ,INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AND DATE_ADD('2011-09-14 23:59:59' ,INTERVAL 5 HOUR)

Thanks a lot for the help...